# Migrate Java Swing ANT based application to GCP

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, ant

We have a ANT based Java Swing application which currently get deployed on Solaris. We build .deb file for download and piggyback on on-premise server to download for user. Now, as we are moving to GCP, I am doing research to make it as smooth as possible. I have following concern in this regard:

1. Kubernetes runs containers so we need to deploy container images, so do I have to build a container image as one of the build or can I store .deb build some where on GCP volume to download ?
2. If build process need to be change, how to approach containerization of ANT based Java Swing project?

Answer (score 0):

The basic deployable unit in Kubernetes is a [Pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/). If you want to create `Pod`/`Deployment` resources, you need to specify container image you want to run and there is no way to use `.deb` package instead.

You can use already existing **Apache Ant** image e.g. [webratio/ant](https://hub.docker.com/r/webratio/ant) as your base container image or create new one by defining a [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/).
For more information on creating and deploying containerized applications, see this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/hello-app).

Of course you don't have to manually build container images every time, you may use CI/CD software such as [Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-gke) or [GitLab CI/CD](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html) to build an image and even deploy resources on Kubernetes cluster.

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor still searching for more clear and simpler solution, as I feel we don't need to create container image as we just need user to download .deb file from a link. The solution I was thinking is to put .deb on GCP volume and add it's link on the site. Perhaps, you can shed more light on possible solution, thanks!